# Best practice for structuring git branches

Tags: git, github

Ok, so I am starting to get really confused about my mess of git branches. Some background: I have my main, official repo at simplare/stoffi-web and my personal fork over at ephracis/stoffi-web. I usually do a feature branch, work on it, do a pull request back to simplare and then merge it into my own fork.

I usually use both the command line and the app Github for Windows/Mac. I clone and commit in the apps, while I do stuff like rebase and handle submodules in the command line.

First question: is this good practice or should I merge the feature branch into my personal fork before doing a PR?

Next, I have gotten into a bit of a mess. I get this message:

```
$ git merge simplare/master
warning: refname 'simplare/master' is ambiguous.
Already up-to-date.

$ git branch -a
* master
  simplare/master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/master
  remotes/simplare/master
```

Second question: how do I clean this up?

Third question: should simplare/master be a "normal" branch or a remote branch? I believe that's why I am getting the ambiguous warning, because I currently have both.

Comment: For third run `git remote -v` and you will answer your question. Examine [git docs](http://gitref.org/remotes/) on how to manipulate this list

Comment: I don't get your hint. My remotes looks as they always have (origin and simplare).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question 1:

The process should be:

1. create a feature branch on `origin`
2. make a PR into `simplare` with that feature branch
3. once `simplare` merges your feature, pull down onto your `origin` master

Reason to not merge your feature branch into `origin` before making a PR into `simplare` is that your PR could get rejected and your `origin` will have the wrong code.

### Question 2:

Just remove the local branch:

```
$ git branch -d simplare/master
```

### Questions 3:

`simplare` should be a remote branch.

Answer (score 3):

> I usually do a feature branch, work on it, do a pull request back to
>   simplare and then merge it into my own fork.

We have your problem right there: as long as everything is fast-forward merging, this works as well as pulling from simplare.

However, if someone else changes a file in the time between you send in your PR and you merge your own branch into your own main branch, you might be ending up with a conflict later on.

The mechanism should be as followed:

1. On your own main branch (assuming that's master): `git pull upstream master`
2. Creating a feature branch: `git checkout -b my_new_feature_branch`
3. do your work; if something in simplare/master changes that you *want* to use, you cann pull simplare/master here.
4. Pull request
5. as soon as merged into simplare , delete your feature branch and `git checkout master; git pull upstream master`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot the part of syncing with simplare as I work. But you didn't actually answer any of my questions: should I merge my feature branch with my own master before I send a PR, and how do I clean up my current local branches and keep them clean?

Comment: Hi @ChristofferBrodd-Reijer: I do think it answers your "should I merge with my own master?": No, you shouldn't, unless you want what happens there to be available in your feature branch; that's why point 3. is a bit longer.

also, I answer how you should keep your local branches clean: After the PR is merged, delete them. You should always pull in master if, and only if, you want the things that changed there in your feature branches.

Comment: Shouldn't my own master always be kept in sync with the master upstream? Right before the PR they would be identical, right?

Comment: @ChristofferBrodd-Reijer: updating your master branch before opening a PR for another branch doesn't even have any visible effect. The idea of this workflow is that all changes should be fast-forwardable, so unless things in the files that you've changed in your feature branch have changed, pulling in the upstream master is purely optional.

Comment: So I take it that the PR should always be `ephracis/feature -> simplare/master` and never a merge of `ephracis/feature` into `ephracis/master` followed by a PR for `ephracis/master -> simplare/master`. Is this correct?

Comment: Another way to put it is if you merge a origin feature branch into your own master branch first, then make a pull request into `simplare` what's the point of working on a feature branch? Why wouldn't you just work on origin/master? You should create a feature branch on origin, make a pull request into `simplare`, once that PR gets merged, you can pull into your master from `simplare`